# BQ array lookup: similar to NTH, but based on index, not position

Tags: multidimensional-array, nested, google-bigquery

The NTH function is really useful for extracting nested array elements in BQ, but its utility for a given table depends on each row's nested array containing the same amount of elements, and in the same order. If I have a 2+ column nested array where one column is variable name/ID, and the different instances of the array in different rows have inconsistent naming and/or ordering, is there an elegant way to fetch/pivot a variable based on the variable name/ID?

For example, if row1 has customDimensions array:

`index    value
4         aaa
23        bbb
70        ccc`

and row2 has customDimensions array:

`index    value
4          ddd
70         eee`

I'd want to run something like

```
SELECT 
NTHLOOKUP(70, customdims.index, customdims.value) as val70,
NTHLOOKUP(4, customdims.index, customdims.value) as val4,
NTHLOOKUP(23, customdims.index, customdims.value) as val23
from my_table;
```

And get:

`val70   val4    val23
ccc aaa bbb
eee ddd (null)`

I've been able to get this sort of result by making a subquery for each desired index value, unnesting the array in each and filtering `WHERE index = (value)`, but that gets really ugly as the variables pile up. Is there an alternative?

EDIT: Based on Mikhail's answer below (thank you!!) I was able to write my query more elegantly. Not quite as slick as an NTHLOOKUP, but I'll take it:

```
select id,
max(case when index = 41 then value[OFFSET(0)] else '' end) as val41,
max(case when index = 59 then value[OFFSET(0)] else '' end) as val59
from
(select
        concat(array1.thing1, array1.thing2) as id,
        cd.index,
        ARRAY_AGG(distinct cd.value) as value
        FROM my_table g
        ,unnest(array1) as array1
        ,unnest(array1.customDimensions) as cd
        where index in (41,59)
        group by 1,2
        order by 1,2
) x
group by 1
order by 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can "offer" is below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.my_table` AS (
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>
    [(4, 'aaa'), (23, 'bbb'), (70, 'ccc')] customDimensions 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>
    [(4, 'ddd'), (70, 'eee')] customDimensions 
)
SELECT cd.index, ARRAY_AGG(cd.value) VALUES
FROM `project.dataset.my_table`,
UNNEST(customDimensions) cd
GROUP BY cd.index
```

with result as below

```sql
Row index   values   
1   4       aaa  
            ddd  
2   23      bbb  
3   70      ccc  
            eee
```

I would recommend to stay with this flatten version as it serves most of practical cases I can think of

But if you still want to further pivot this -  there are quite a number of posts related to how to `pivot` in BigQuery

Answer (score 1):

> I've been able to get this sort of result by making a subquery for each desired index value, unnesting the array in each and filtering `WHERE index = (value)`, but that gets really ugly as the variables pile up. Is there an alternative?

Yes, you can use a user-defined function to encapsulate the common logic. For example,

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION NTHLOOKUP(
  targetIndex INT64,
  customDimensions ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>>
) AS (
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions)
   WHERE index = targetIndex)
);

SELECT 
  NTHLOOKUP(70, customDimensions) as val70,
  NTHLOOKUP(4, customDimensions) as val4,
  NTHLOOKUP(23, customDimensions) as val23
from my_table;
```